# Get Java's class name using Javascript or PHP

Tags: java, javascript, php

I need to find out the class name from Java code. For example: The target file is aa.txt, the content of this file is as below:

```
public class HelloWorld{
     public static void main(String []args){
           System.out.println("Hello World!!!!");
       }
}
```

I want to find out the class name, in this case is `HelloWorld` so that I can name the .java file as `HelloWorld.java`.

My question is how can I get Java class name in PHP or JavaScript?

Add:

I will let users to write very simple Java code in my webpage, and I will save their code in files, run their code and return results for them. But right, there may be more than one class in a file.

Comment: Can you describe the context for this operation? Also, note that a single Java source file can define many different classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP:

```
$source = preg_replace('/\/\*[\s\S]*\*\/|\/\/.*|"(?:\\\\?.)*?"/', '', $source);
if (preg_match('/\bclass\s+(\w+)/', $source, $matches)) {
    $className = $matches[1];
}
```

It strips comments and strings then pulls out the name of the first declared class. (This doesn't handle [Unicode escapes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.3) but they're probably a non-issue as they're never practically used outside of strings.)